# How to use cec control in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple loop in python that can turn of and on your tv using CEC control. But, whenever I try to "import cec" into my program it doesn't work. I am new to programing and I don't really know where to start.

[image]

Comment: have you installed cec?

Comment: please provide error

Comment: Did you install `cec`: https://github.com/trainman419/python-cec

Comment: Try `pip install cec` to install the package prior to running. You may need to install required dependencies or set up path (see @DavidCullen's link).

Answer (score 1):

looking at the error, it looks like you didn't install it. so, using your terminal in your editor, paste or type

> pip install pyCEC

you can [check the website here](https://pypi.org/project/pyCEC/)

and if it didn't work restart you editor.
then it will work perfectly.

Comment: Also make sure you have `libcec` installed on your machine.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `cec` is a python package: https://pypi.org/project/cec/

Depending on your python installation, you can likely install it with `pip install cec`.

See this documentation on getting started with python packages for more:
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/